# CasperJS and Parallel Crawling

Tags: phantomjs, casperjs, gnu-parallel

I'm trying to crawl some website. However my crawling process is so long i need to use multiple instances to shorten it. I've searched for other ways and aborted all the unnecessary resources requested still it's way too slow for me(around 8-9 secs).

What is the easiest way to parallel casperjs instances or even run only two casperjs at the same time to crawl in parallel?

I have used parallel gnu from a blog post i've found however it seems like although the process' are alive they are not crawling in parallel because total execution time is still the same with one instance.

Should i use a nodejs server to create instances?
What is the easiest and most practical way?

Comment: You might be hitting physical or artificial limits of the server. Can you check this?

Answer (score 0):

Can you adapt this:
https://www.gnu.org/software/parallel/man.html#EXAMPLE:-Breadth-first-parallel-web-crawler-mirrorer

```
  #!/bin/bash

  # E.g. http://gatt.org.yeslab.org/
  URL=$1
  # Stay inside the start dir
  BASEURL=$(echo $URL | perl -pe 's:#.*::; s:(//.*/)[^/]*:$1:')
  URLLIST=$(mktemp urllist.XXXX)
  URLLIST2=$(mktemp urllist.XXXX)
  SEEN=$(mktemp seen.XXXX)

  # Spider to get the URLs
  echo $URL >$URLLIST
  cp $URLLIST $SEEN

  while [ -s $URLLIST ] ; do
    cat $URLLIST |
      parallel lynx -listonly -image_links -dump {} \; \
        wget -qm -l1 -Q1 {} \; echo Spidered: {} \>\&2 |
        perl -ne 's/#.*//; s/\s+\d+.\s(\S+)$/$1/ and do { $seen{$1}++ or print }' |
      grep -F $BASEURL |
      grep -v -x -F -f $SEEN | tee -a $SEEN > $URLLIST2
    mv $URLLIST2 $URLLIST
  done

  rm -f $URLLIST $URLLIST2 $SEEN
```

Comment: Hey, thanks for the answer however, I can't adapt that, because the web page I am crawling requires javascript enabled and with wget or curl i can only get the first part of the page.

Comment: Can you build a tool that can export the links like: 'lynx -listonly -image_links -dump URL' and a tool that can get the page like 'wget -qm -l1 -Q1 URL' then you should be golden: Simply replace lynx/wget in the script above. This is what I meant by 'adapt'.